# If a CTE is spilling out to tempDB, would a temp table be a better option?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that uses a CTE to define staff departments.

The CTE is spilling out to tempdb when the query optimizer opts for a hash match join.

- In cases like this would it be better practice to use a temporary table instead of a CTE?
- Is there any cost in SQL trying to handle the CTE in memory but then having to use tempdb that can be mitigated by deliberately directing it to use tempdb?

If it's helpful, my code looks like this:

```
;WITH cte_Staff_Departments
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        [stf].[contact_id]
        , CASE
            WHEN [stf].[department] NOT IN('HR', 'SALES', 'IT')
                THEN [dpt].[department]
                ELSE [stf].[department]
            END AS [Department]
    FROM [dbo].[staff] AS [stf]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[departments] AS [dpt] ON [stf].[contact_id] = [dpt].[contact_id]
    WHERE ([stf].[ownership_group] in ('COR','SLE')
        OR [dpt].[ownership_group] in ('COR','SLE')
) 
select contact_id, department from cte_Staff_Departments
```

Thanks
LS23

Comment: The query within the CTE doesn't look like it should specifically be a problem, unless it's returning a huge number of rows and `DISTINCT` has to therefore eliminate a lot of them (is that the case?). For what you have though, the CTE isn't even needed, as you're simply returning the dataset from the CTE

Comment: If the optimizer is spilling rows to tempdb (Is it spool operators?), then it is in effect deciding to create something quite like a temp table itself. Why do you think you saying it explicitly is going to be better than that? And what if, due to data changes, upgrades, pathcing etc, spilling to tempdb is no longer optimal? If you've re-written your code to explicitly use a temp table, you've stopped the optimizer from doing the best it can here.

Comment: Do you have indexes covering your predicates?

Comment: did you check if [stf].[contact_id] and [dpt].[contact_id] are indexed. That will surely improve performance.

Comment: There's no point in using this CTE. Just use the query as-is. Performance is affected by *indexes* and data though. What does the executino plan look like? Are `contact_id`, `ownership_group` covered by indexes?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, they're really helpful. I've checked and both [stf].[contact_id] and [dpt].[contact_id] are indexed using a CI and a NCI respectively. I've re-written the query and ditched the CTE in the process. It's faster!

Answer (score 0):

@lindsayScott23, I am only suggesting. Please dont mark me down. I will actually do away with the CTE and write the query with a subquery. like this:

```
SELECT contact_id, department 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        [stf].[contact_id], 
        CASE
            WHEN [stf].[department] NOT IN('HR', 'SALES', 'IT')
                THEN [dpt].[department]
                ELSE [stf].[department]
        END AS [Department]
    FROM [dbo].[staff] AS [stf]
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[departments] AS [dpt] 
            ON [stf].[contact_id] = [dpt].[contact_id]
            AND (
                [stf].[ownership_group] in ('COR','SLE')
                OR 
                [dpt].[ownership_group] in ('COR','SLE')
            )
) CSD
GROUP BY
    contact_id, department
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I gave that a try and it produced exactly the same plan as using the CTE. It's a useful suggestion tho' as my peers would be more familiar with a subquery than with CTEs if and when they need to look at my code.

Comment: There's no real difference between a CTE and a subquery. The CTE isn't the problem. The indexes, data are. `DISTINCT` will always result in grouping, sorting and possibly spilling if the data doesn't fit in memory. In fact, there's no need for either a subquery or a CTE. Just execute the `SELECT` query inside the CTE